# What are the steps to get root access in android emulator for rebooting through code?

Tags: android, root, reboot

How do I get root access in order to reboot the emulator? How do I kill all unwanted processes along with the child process?

Comment: hi all, i m a newbie to android.i wanna reboot android emulator through code.i know that root access is required,but no one have clearly explained about how to get root access in order to reboot the emulator.i tried installing binary su but even then in terminal emulator i get as su access denied.

ps-after rebooting i also wanted to kill all unwanted process except my specific app and its child process alone to run in emulator.

Comment: With something "odd" like this, it may be more productive to explain what you want to actually accomplish before getting deep into the details of the method you have in mind, which may not turn out to be the best way (or even a possible way) to achieve your ultimately needed functionality.

Comment: @chris my overall idea is,whenever the user opens up a secure app which uses inernet,the emulator should reboot when clicking in the specific app so that it will kill malicious processes running if any.ao after rebooting i want all the processes including background processes to be killed except my specfic app process alone to run in emulator..this is to enhance the security in android m doin for ma final yr proj

Comment: This is not a practical way to do things.  A malicious process can just register a boot complete receiver and start again on reboot.  Getting into a fight with the android runtime where it starts things and you kill them and it starts them again is a loosing proposition.  To do something approaching what you want, you need to make a custom build of android with behavior different than the ordinary.  Please either pick a different project, or be prepared for one presenting several times more work than you imagined, as you re-engineer your own mobile operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You have already root access to your emulator. To kill a process and all childs just use the device view in eclipse, select the emulator theere and chose which process you want to kill.

I have no idea on how to restart from code if you are looking for that. Rebooting the device should be easy: just close it and than boot it up again.

(I have the feeling I don't really get what you want...)

Comment: i get root access only in adb but inside terminal emulator,i get as 'uid 10014 not allowed to su'.

Comment: i wanna reboot emulator via code,@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_REBOOT);
        i.putExtra("nowait", 1);
        i.putExtra("interval", 1);
        i.putExtra("window", 0);
        sendBroadcast(i); } } when run this code,in emulator it says  app is not installed and in console it shows ActivityManager:[1]   Killed am start -n com.i think now u get it.

Answer (score 0):

Most su binaries for Android depend on SuperUser.apk (available for free through the market). The su binary uses this apk to ask the user if it's ok to do whatever is being requested (and the user can opt to remember the answer). If you're using such a su, you need to also have that apk.

Once the pieces are in place, your application can spawn a process with the right arguments... something like argv[0]="/path/to/su", argv[1]="-c", argv[2]="(whatever command you want to run)", argv[3...n]=arguments to your command.

Comment: how to find the key which was required to sign system apps?

Answer (score 0):

To kill a process in the command line, simply issue the following command line on the shell:

```
kill-9 YOUR_PID
```

If you know the name of the process, but not the pid, use

```
kill -9 $(pidof NAME_OF_PROCESS)
```

You can also use it on your code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill-9 YOUR_PID");
```

Check the man page for more details: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill

Answer (score 0):

> ps-after rebooting i also wanted to kill all unwanted process except my specific app and its child process alone to run in emulator.

If that is really what you want to do - repurpose an android build as a generic embedded linux, then the way to go about it is to regenerate a ramdisk image (which android packs onto the kernel) containing an init.rc which launches your application rather than the android native services and (java-esque dalvik) android runtime.  Rebuilding the ramdisk requires a unix-like OS and that arcane cpio command line which you can find in  web search.  I'd be tempted to leave the startup of ADB in there so you can debug the various things which will go wrong.

For testing purposes simply typing "stop" from the adb shell will shut down the android runtime and give you a UI-less virtual pocket linux box.  There will still be some native services running but they may be more help than harm.  Ultimately you may need to set OOM killer values on the things you add, though without the runtime up that may not be an issue in the near term if you don't consume much memory.

Or if what you want to do is have a very locked down and limited UI built on top of the android runtime, you would instead develop a custom home screen , test this on an unmodified emulator, and then deploy it on a build customized to lack any means of installing other applications.